# ngModel binding for ng-bootstrap radio button does not work in Angular 2 when jQuery script is added

Tags: jquery, angular, ng-bootstrap

The binding works when I have the following code in my Angular 2 app:

```
<!-- script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script-->
<script src="node_modules/tether/dist/js/tether.min.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But the console in browser gives the following error:

> bootstrap.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery. jQuery must be included before Bootstrap's JavaScript.
>       at bootstrap.min.js:6

But when I add it (by removing the comment), binding does not work.

app.component.html:

```
<div [(ngModel)]="model" ngbRadioGroup name="radioBasic">
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" [value]="1"> Left (pre-checked)
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" value="middle"> Middle
</label>
<label class="btn btn-primary">
<input type="radio" [value]="false"> Right
</label>
</div>
<hr>
<pre>{{model}}</pre>
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but does this depend on the jQuery version? What are you using at the moment?

Comment: Don't use jquery & bootstrap.js why do you need them?

Comment: @ConorReidd I am using jQuery v3.2.1, Angular v4.0.3, Bootstrap 4
@r

Comment: @RomanC I only know of bootstrap for making nice looking interfaces. Any other suggestion is also welcome.

Comment: @Anurag See answer below, nice looking interfaces are not related to your question.

Comment: Did as suggested in the answer. Great help. Thanks to all of you!

Comment: I'm facing the same problem, could you solve it without removing jquery.js? I don't want to use ng-bootstrap because it hasn't all the components that plain old bootstrap provides

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of the [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) project is to *get rid* of the dependency on bootstrap.js *and* jQuery. The reasoning here is that we can drop unneeded dependencies and offer APIs that are more natural in the Angular world.

So, as others commented, do NOT add dependencies on Bootstrap's JavaScript (and skip jQuery while you are at it). Follow the ng-bootstrap's installation instructions instead: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/getting-started

What you need from Bootstrap is only CSS, no need for JavaScript part.

Comment: The Bootstrap nav menus do not work without its JS files.  Additionally, I removed the files from my ng-cli config file, and I STILL am getting the error.